# How do I find out what exception was thrown in the Xcode debugger (for iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, exception

I'm learning iPhone programming from Erica Sadun's The iPhone Developer's Cookbook.  When I run the app I created by following the steps in the Temperature Conversion Example starting on page 81 in the simulator, it terminates due to an uncaught exception.  (See http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesdk/browse_frm/thread/6f44a90fdb8da28a?hl=en for the question I posted to the iPhoneSDK Google Group.)

The exception is thrown after calling UIApplicationMain() from my main().  If I look through the stack trace in the debugger, all I see is (of course) assembly.  How do I find out what kind of exception was thrown?

**Update**:
Learning the details of the exception from the Debugger Console was enough to help me solve the problem.  (See http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesdk/browse_frm/thread/6f44a90fdb8da28a?hl=en.)  I verified that I could set a symbolic breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`, but I didn't look to see if the backtrace from there would have been helpful.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Put a breakpoint at `objc_exception_throw` and run your app via Debug instead of Run

To clarify, what you're actually seeing when you get an exception without the breakpoint is the same stack trace always - it's the uncaught exception handler. The type of exception is logged to the Run console, but if you want to see a backtrace for where the exception was raised, that's what the breakpoint is for.

Comment: Hit ⌘⌥B, select Run → Show → Breakpoints, or select Run → Manage Breakpoints → Add Symbolic Breakpoint.

Comment: After you stop in the debugger, you can enter `po $eax` (simulator) or `po $r0` (device) to see the exception. This is because the exception object is passed as the first argument to objc_exception_throw, which is kept in register r0 or EAX. HTH

Comment: In Xcode 4.5.2 you can find it at: Product → Debug → Create Symbolic Breakpoint...

Comment: Also make sure that you have selected "objc_exception_throw" in the debug navigator and not the bothersome "main.m" while entering "po $eax".

Comment: @EthanHolshouser: No it's not. The simulator uses the host architecture of your computer. The only difference is when simulating an arm64 binary, the simulator will run x86_64 instead of i386, which makes it `$rdi` instead of `$eax`. Similarly, on an actual arm64 device, you probably want `$x0` instead of `$r0`.

Comment: @EthanHolshouser: I actually tested before commenting, on the off chance that they were in fact translating the register name. `po $r0` did not work in an iPhone 6 simulator in Xcode 6.1 beta. I tried both armv7 and arm64 simulation.

Comment: Interestingly, on the arm64 simulator (which is x86_64), there's synonyms `$arg1`, `$arg2`, etc for the registers, so you don't have to remember `$rdi`. Unfortunately this isn't true on the armv7 simulator (which is i386). I don't know if it's true for device debugging because I'm not set up at the moment to actually run code on a device. You can see if this is true with `register read -A`, which prints the "alternate name" for each register, if there is one.

Comment: Also, `HTH` means `hope it helps` for others that are used to read words.

Comment: @nielsbot, For me, `$eax` doesn't work no more, instead, I use `$rax`.

Comment: $eax is 32-bit vs $rax is 64-bit x86-64 I believe. Also looks like $arg1 may work based on @KevinBallard's comment.

Answer (score 15):

In the new Xcode (at least starting from v4.5), you can catch all exceptions easily by doing this:

1. Bring up breakpoint navigator (⌘6)
2. Click + on the bottom left
3. Add Exception Breakpoint

I think the above is the same as a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`. http://samwize.com/2012/09/26/xcode-4-dot-5-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 6):

http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/11/28/debugging-exceptions-in-xcode-4-2/

Same as samewize's solution, but also shows how to make this breakpoint show up by default in all your projects (right click on breakpoint, Move Breakpoint To, User).

Answer (score 3):

As Kevin answered, you will find more helpful debugging info by setting a breakpoint at `objc_exception_throw`.

If you are using Xcode 4.2, you can add this symbolic breakpoint by going to Breakpoint Navigator > Click on the add icon on the bottom left > Add symbolic breakpoint > Enter `objc_exception_throw` for Symbol > Done.

Comment: Better late than never. This shall be the first thing I do for every project henceforth. Super useful. Thanks Daryl Spitzer, @kevin-ballard and samwize