# XCode: Find out what exception was thrown while stopped at an exception breakpoint

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64

I'm stopped at an exception breakpoint. How can I use the LLDB console to tell which exception was thrown?

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384775/how-do-i-find-out-what-exception-was-thrown-in-the-xcode-debugger-for-iphone#comment11231631_384795) I should be able to type `po $r0` to see the exception object "because it is passed as the first argument to `objc_exception_throw`" but this register doesn't appear to exist on ARM64.

After reading the [iOS ABI Function Call Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Articles/ARM64FunctionCallingConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013702-SW1) I also tried `po $x0` but registers `x0` through `x18` are all empty.

I'm using XCode 5.1, iOS 7.1 on ARM64.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct stack frame selected (i.e. the objc_exception_throw frame)?

Comment: I'll make it an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have the correct stack frame selected (i.e. the objc_exception_throw frame)?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155495/how-do-i-get-exception-details-in-xcode-4-6), your `po $x0` should work.

Comment: An alternative on ARM64 is also `po $arg1` up to `po $arg6`. Thanks for the help

Comment: @bcattle Huh! I didn't know that. Cool!